# How to automatically determine d3.layout.tree size?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have not been able to find any [D3 API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) documentation that would allow you to easily determine the needed width and height for a given d3.layout.tree, or any other layout, to ensure that no nodes overlap with one another.

For example, the [d3.layout.tree example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) starts to overlap once you expand all child nodes.

Is there a simple D3 method to determine the width and height that my tree needs to be to avoid overlapping? Or, do I have to write my own method?

**EDIT**

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/317) for this behavior to be added at some point in the future.

**EDIT#2**

There is now https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout#nodeSize and https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#nodeSize to set the size of the layout based on the size of each node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is something you would need to create yourself - the tree layout does not know how you are going to represent the tree nodes, labels, and other visual elements (especially the size of those elements) so it doesn't necessarily know they are over-lapping (you could decrease the size of the elements and they would no longer be doing so).  As such, I don't believe it would be possible to build something like this into the tree layout functionality.

You could consider dynamically setting the width (or height, as appropriate) by using a 'basewidth' variable and multiplying that by the number of 'final' nodes being displayed.